# как в адресную строку ввести параметр get с клавиатуры

Tags: php, html, mysql

как в адресную строку вместо $переменная

```
printf("<p><a href='test.php?sub=%s&limit=$переменная'><font size='2px'>%s</font></a><p />",$myrow28["id"],$myrow28["name"]);
```

водить значение c  клавиатуры, чтобы limit передавало его и можна было получить через пост, как например передается в sub, может быть как то форму запроса составить?

Comment: а через js? просто при вводе в какой-то инпут сразу менять значение в вашей ссылке?

Comment: Нужно задать значение limit, так как с него через гет потом значение вставляется в sql запрос

Comment: какой у вас процес? Вы хотите осуществлять вставку в запрос при переходе по этой ссылке?, но перед переходом должна былть возможность пользователю поменять значение limit?

Comment: Да, если конкретно то sub-учебный предмет для проведения тестирования, а limit - количество вопросов этого теста, и если sub работает отлично, то limit работает только когда в ссылке стоит конкретное число, напр 2, и выводит 2 вопроса, нужно сделать, чтобы количество вопросов менялось пользователем

Comment: так чем вам не нравится мой вариант?
 задаете инпут какой-то, при его смене пользователем, динамически меняете строку перехода, а уже на странице проверяете к-во вопросов, если оно есть, если нету, задаете какое-то дефолтное значение.

Comment: Можете на примере написать, я уже много всего пробовал

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ra21fu9n/
ну, а там уже ставите себе ограничения, чтобы только цифры, макс. к-во ввода, и другие параметры. Можете повешать событие не на ввод, а на кнопку "принять", и только единожды менять ссылку... Как вам там будет удобно.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('input', function () {
  
    value = $('input').val();
  var href_start = $('a').attr('href');
 var limit_start = href_start.match(/limit=([^&]*)/);
 var limit_res = "limit=" + value;
 var href_res = href_start.replace(limit_start[0], limit_res);
  $('a').attr('href', href_res);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<p><a href='test.php?sub=%s&limit='><font size='2px'>Ссылка для смены</font></a><p />
```

Ну, а ограничения сами уж делайте для ввода.